# Display only file name in FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a webpage in asp.net 3.5 that uses the FileUpload control. When a user clicks on the "Browse" button (which is part of the control) the control displays a file select popup (dialog box). When the user selects the file which they wish to upload, by default the full path to the file is shown in the textbox (which is also part of the control); **however, I wish for it to only display the file name and not the full path.** Anyone know of a slick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that isn't possible. You cannot set the value inside of the FileUpload control's textbox at anytime, via server side or client side script.

Answer (score 2):

The FileUpload control is essentially an html `<input type="file">`

As such, the browser determines how to render it.  You have no control over this.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the native file input control won't do this.  You may be able to work around that with some overlaid styling of the control, however.  Start [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_custom_file_input_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/).  It'll likely take a little bit of JavaScript to break out the file name from the path, display only the latter (in the custom non-control elements), but use both when it matters (in the control itself).  But it should be doable.

Comment: You can't change it via JavaScript either. It will not work as expected and will cause security exceptions

Comment: @Scott Schluer: The idea here isn't to change the value on the control, but to hide the control from view and present the user with some custom elements which act like the control, pass events to it, but display only what the developer wants to display.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't realize that jQuery had a custom control for this. The control shown on the page of the link is doing exactly what I need. I'll take a closer look at it and see if it's the solution that I'm looking for.

Comment: You may want to edit your question then to get a better response. Your question reads like you specifically want to change the textbox value: " by default the full path to the file is shown in the textbox (which is also part of the control); however, I wish for it to only display the file name and not the full path."